# What's the meaning of 'the some sort of race condition' here?

Tags: penetration-test

> I tried probably 50 different types of payloads there until I realized that the problem is actually with what appeared to be some sort of race condition with PhantomJS.

Source:[escalating-xss-in-phantomjs-image-rendering-to-ssrflocal-file-read](http://buer.haus/2017/06/29/escalating-xss-in-phantomjs-image-rendering-to-ssrflocal-file-read/)
I can't understand the meaning of 'some sort of race condition' here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A race condition is a bug which only happens when a system executes multiple tasks in parallel and these parallel tasks get finished in a specific order.

In this specific case, the author wants an instance of phantom.js (a headless web browser) to execute a javascript payload and then take a screenshot of the result. This fails because sometimes the screenshot is taken before Phantom.JS is finished executing the javascript payload.